# matplotlib: latex: savefig: OSError no such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, latex, cluster-computing

I am generating some png figures with `python 2.7.3` and `Agg` backend and using the options:

```
matplotlib.rc('font', family = 'serif', serif = 'cm10', size = 19)
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex = True)
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\boldmath']
matplotlib.rcParams['font.weight']         = 'bold'
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.linewidth']      = 2
```

for the labels and titles in the figures. the code works fine when I run it on my cluster on a login node. When I submit it to a computing node I get

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 312, in <module>
     main()
   File "plotvoigt.py", line 97, in main
     plt.savefig(savefilename, format = 'png')
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 696, in savefig
     res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1563, in savefig
     self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2232, in print_figure
     **kwargs)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 527, in print_png
     FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 474, in draw
     self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 62, in draw_wrapper
     draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1159, in draw
     func(*args)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 62, in draw_wrapper
     draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2319, in draw
     a.draw(renderer)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 62, in draw_wrapper
     draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1110, in draw
     renderer)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1060, in _get_tick_bboxes
     extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 961, in get_window_extent
     bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 352, in _get_layout
     ismath=False)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 229, in get_text_width_height_descent
     renderer=self)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 678, in get_text_width_height_descent
     page = next(iter(dvi))
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 89, in __iter__
     have_page = self._read()
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 150, in _read
     self._dispatch(byte)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 233, in _dispatch
     self._fnt_def(k, c, s, d, a, l, n)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 388, in _fnt_def
     tfm = _tfmfile(fontname)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 897, in _tfmfile
     return _fontfile(texname, Tfm, '.tfm', _tfmcache)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 887, in _fontfile
     filename = find_tex_file(texname + suffix)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 868, in find_tex_file
     stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
     errread, errwrite)
   File "/path/Python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
     raise child_exception
 OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

but then if I remove these matplotlib options and I remove the labels the figures are saved on the computing node without a problem.

How can I use latex for typesetting the figures on the computing node?

Comment: You need to make sure to have "a working LaTeX installation, dvipng (which may be included with your LaTeX installation), and Ghostscript (GPL Ghostscript 8.60 or later is recommended). The executables for these external dependencies must all be located on your PATH." (taken from [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html)). You also need to make sure you have writing access and that the font you want to use is actually available in the latex installation.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest in fact you where right, I needed to load the module file for latex